# Connection fault in IB

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have a Tab Bar application with four new headers, implementation and interface files, and added those as the sources in IB. They were in this format: `FirstView.h/m/xib`, `SecondView.h/m/xib`.

I then had files for First-, Second-, Third- and FourthView.
There was also a file there called `FirstViewController`. I did not touch this, I just deleted it because I wasn't going to need it.

I then laid out my interface for the first view (`FirstView.h/m/xib`) in IB. It had an image on the top, label under and a `UITableView` under that.

I sat up the correct connections (delegations and datasource for the tableview) in my `FirstView.h/m` file, and pressed Build. It seemed to build without errors, so I pressed Build and Go.

The Simulator popped up, installed the app and *crashed*. (Error message:`Terminating app due to uncaught exception`).

Complete error message:

```
2010-02-06 21:50:54.733 Mudo[52439:207] *** -[FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x39101a0
2010-02-06 21:50:54.735 Mudo[52439:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x39101a0'
2010-02-06 21:50:54.736 Mudo[52439:207] Stack: (**LotsOfNumbers**)
```

I asked about this in another question, got an answer, and that fixed it:

It was obviously looking for code in the `FirstViewController.h/m`-file, although I did not do anything to make it look for code there.

I fixed this by adding two interfaces and implementations in my FirstView.h/m file. (FirstView and FirstViewController)

**When I ran the app then, the table view and tab bar came up on the screen, but my image and label did NOT.**
I don't have any idea of why it was looking for the code in FirstViewController instead of FirstView... I have the correct connections in IB, too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tableview is trying to query its data source for the number of rows it should display.  If you've connected the tableview's datasource outlet to an instance of your `FirstViewController` class, then you need to implement `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` in that class.